# Difference tcl script tkconsole to load gro file in VMD

Tags: tcl, vmd

My problem is simple: I'm trying to write a tcl script to use $grofile instead writing every time I need this file name.
So, what I did in TkConsole was:

```
% set grofile "file.gro"

% mol load gro ${grofile}
```

and, indeed, I succeeded uploading the file.
In the script I have the same lines, but still have this error:

> > wrong # args: should be "set varName ?newValue?"
> >
> > can't read "grofile": no such variable

I tried to solve my problem with

```
% set grofile [./file.gro]
```

and I have this error,

> > invalid command name "./file.gro"
> >
> > can't read "grofile": no such variable

I tried also with

```
% set grofile [file ./file.gro r]
```

and I got the first error, again.

I haven't found any simple way to avoid using the explicit name of the file I want to upload. It seems like you only can use the most trivial, but tedious way:

```
mol load file.gro
mol addfile file.xtc
```

and so on and so on...

Can you help me with a brief explanation about why in the TkConsole I can upload the file and use it as a variable while I can not in the tcl script?
Also, if you have where is my mistake, I will appreciate it.

I apologize if it is basic, but I could not find any answer. Thanks.

I add the head of my script:

```
set grofile "sim.part0001_protein_lipid.gro"
set xtcfile "protein_lipid.xtc"
set intime  "0-5ms"
set system  "lower"
source view_change_render.tcl
source cg_bonds.tcl

mol load gro $grofile xtc ${system}_${intime}_${xtcfile}
```

It was solved, thanks for your help.

Comment: apparently you don't have exactly the same code. Show the script file here.

Comment: Thanks Glenn. I tried many times until it worked. I wonder if maybe there is kind of bug. My concern was about the fact that in the terminal I was writing exactly what I wrote in the script. Now it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

You may think you've typed the same thing, but you haven't. I'm guessing that your real filename has spaces in it, and that you've not put double-quotes around it. That will confuse `set` as Tcl's general parser will end up giving `set` more arguments than it expects. (Tcl's general parser *does not* know that `set` only takes one or two arguments, by very long standing policy of the language.)

So you should ***really*** do:

```
set grofile "file.gro"
```

***Don't leave the double quotes out*** if you have a complicated name.

---

Also, this won't work:

```
set grofile [./file.gro]
```

because `[`…`]` is used to indicate running something as a command and using the result of that. While `./file.gro` is actually a legal command name in Tcl, it's… highly unlikely.

And this won't work:

```
set grofile [file ./file.gro r]
```

Because the `file` command requires a subcommand as a first argument. The word you give is not one of the standard `file` subcommands, and none of them accept those arguments anyway, which look suitable for `open` (though that returns a channel *handle* suitable for use with commands like `gets` and `read`).

---

The TkConsole is actually pretty reasonable as quick-and-dirty terminal emulations go (given that it omits a lot of the complicated cases). The real problem is that you're not being consistently accurate about what you're really typing; that matters hugely in most programming languages, not just Tcl. You need to learn to be really exacting; cut-n-paste when creating a question helps a lot.